# Phone masking function inserting extra "x's" in form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, masking

My phone masking script is inserting the correct dashes but for numbers with extensions it is adding extra `"x's"` after the 12th character. I am trying to format the mask so it looks like `000-0000x0000000` but it is returning `000-000-0000xxxx0000`. Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
 var phoneNumber = $('#phone_number');
 
 // Adds a phone number mask
   phoneNumber.on('input paste', function(e) {
  var phoneNumStr = e.target.value.split("-").join("");

  // Create a new string with the hyphen
  pro = phoneNumStr.split('').map(function(str, index) {
  
   // Inserts a hyphen after the third and sixth characters
   if (index == 3 || index == 6) {
    return "-" + str;
   } else if (index == 10) {
    return "x" + str;
   } else {
    return str;
   }
  }).join('');
  
  // Returns the new string
  $(this).val(pro);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="phone_number">Phone Number*</label> 
<input type="text" id="phone_number" name="phone_number" maxlength="20">
```

Comment: The string already has an x in it for each subsequent time you enter a number, so it adds another and another and another.  You might consider adding `x` as one of your split characters in addition to the `-` so it is also ignored.

Comment: @Taplar, thank you for your comment. I thought I was telling my conditional that if the index is 10 (nothing before or after) then insert the "x" into the string? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: A possible solution is already in Taplars comment. But for this you will have to have a look at the first parameter of [`.split([separator [, limit]])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#Parameters)

Comment: Side note: beware that this approach prevents the number from being edited since it continually moves cursor to end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed your split '-' to use a regex to split on dash and x to remove the x's from the string that is evaluated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
 var phoneNumber = $('#phone_number');
 
 // Adds a phone number mask
   phoneNumber.on('input paste', function(e) {
                                         //remove dash and x
  var phoneNumStr = e.target.value.split(/[x-]/).join("");

  // Create a new string with the hyphen
  pro = phoneNumStr.split('').map(function(str, index) {
  
   // Inserts a hyphen after the third and sixth characters
   if (index == 3 || index == 6) {
    return "-" + str;
   } else if (index == 10) {
    return "x" + str;
   } else {
    return str;
   }
  }).join('');
  
  // Returns the new string
  $(this).val(pro);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="phone_number">Phone Number*</label> 
   <input type="text" id="phone_number" name="phone_number" maxlength="20">
```

Comment: thank you for your snippet. Is there a way to prevent the cursor from jumping to the end of the string if the user clicks on the "Delete" key?

Comment: That question would be more in line with asking a separate question, as its different from your original question.

Comment: This is the problem with any/all scripts that reformat the input as you type.  Try this: run snippet, type "124", oops, missed the "3", press left once, type 3 - cursor now back at the end.  You need to record the caret position, change the text, then work out where it should be and restore it.  **or** have a label *next* to the input that shows the final formatted version instead of messing with people's inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
var phoneNumber = $('#phone_number');

// Adds a phone number mask
phoneNumber.on('input paste', function(e) {
    var phoneNumStr = e.target.value.split("-").join("");

    // Create a new string with the hyphen
    pro = phoneNumStr.split('').map(function(str, index) {

        // Inserts a hyphen after the third and sixth characters
        if (index == 3 || index == 6) {
            return "-" + str;
        } else if (index == 10) {
            if(str.indexOf("x")==-1)
              return "x" + str;
            else {
              return str;
            }
        } else {
            return str;
        }
    }).join('');

    // Returns the new string
    $(this).val(pro);
});
```

});